# Momentum $k$-space Brillouin zone for non-translational invariant systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, lattice-model

Usually, we define the momentum $k$-space Brillouin zone (by Fourier transformed from the real space $x$ with a wavefunction $\psi(x)$ to the momentum $k$-space) for:

(1) **quadratic non-interacting (free) systems** (such as those can be written in terms of BdG equation.)

and

(2) **translational invariant systems** (so one can define the conjugate momentum $k$ as a good quantum number).

> Question: Could we define the momentum $k$-space Brillouin zone for
>
> **non-translational invariant systems**
>
> but quadratic non-interacting (free) systems? (Namely can we modify (2) to non-translational invariant, for example with random disorder/impurity but keep (1)?)

Comment: Somehow it appears that you have asked this question twice. Possibly due to the internet connection problems, care to delete one of them?

Comment: they are different questions.

Comment: [The corresponding question about systems without quadratic interactions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290065/44126)